# sed unix error: unterminated 's' command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Executing this command:

```
sed -e 's/á/\&#225;/g' ./source_file > ./destiny_file
```

Shows this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
```

Sentence is a part of an .sh file.

I had tried on several shells: sh/bash/sch

And the result is the same.

Comment: On my system (Debian wheezy LTS, all patches applied), it runs without error message, and it does the right thing.

Comment: Also asked [in SO.es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/118192/83), also could not reproduce in my GNU sed 4.2.2.

Comment: What happens, if you replace the *á* by, say *a* (just for testing). Still a syntax error?

Comment: @user1934428, maybe this is the problem. With "a" the error disappears.

Comment: I put "sed -e 's/\xE1/\&#225;/g' ./source_file > ./destiny_file" and works perfectly! Thanks to all!

Comment: That is an interesting point by @user1934428. You can check what locale you are working with. For example `LANG=es_ES.utf8 sed -e 's/á/\&#225;/g' <<< "holá"` works fine to me.

Comment: Yes! We change the server so the problem probably is the locale set. Thank you @fedorqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to codify "á" as "xE1":

```
sed -e 's/\xE1/\&#225\x3B/g'
```

This works ok!